# Is there a way in Prisma to create a field in multiple tables with a common sequence? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I'm trying to create a field for several tables that will represent a common sequence.

I created a migration using `npx prisma migrate dev --create-only`. Then i added sequence creation and altered column.

migration file:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE global_custom_id_sequence INCREMENT 1 START 100;

-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "Section" ADD COLUMN     "custmId" INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE "Section" ALTER COLUMN "custmId" SET DEFAULT nextval('global_custom_id_sequence');
```

On the next migration prisma adds following:

```
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "Section" ALTER COLUMN "custmId" DROP DEFAULT;
DROP SEQUENCE "global_custom_id_sequence";
```

Is there a way out of this situation so that Prisma does not delete fields and sequence?